# Android - Error Manifest merger failed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

i just download Android Material (Project Files) from CodeCanyon, but when opened and Build with Android Studio, i get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ListViewAnimations-core-slh:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [android - AS:StickyListHeaders:unspecified] 

C:\android - AS\ListViewAnimations-core-slh\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android - AS\StickyListHeaders\unspecified\AndroidManifest.xml

Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders" to force usage
```

This Android Material Project contain many modules, one of them that caused error is **StickListHeaders**, here's the `AndroidManifest.xml` of **StickListHeaders** module :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

What is wrong with AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I was able to fix it by opening `ListViewAnimations-core-slh\build.gradle` file and add the following code inside the `android` section:

`defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should try below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.project.path">
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders" />
</manifest>
```

Notice: package is your package of your project. Hope to help you!

Comment: thanks, but now appear : `Error:(54, 13) error: cannot find symbol method setElevation(View,int)` in one if my class

Comment: but what is setElevation method used for ? is it extended from View ? why they are unkown now ?

Comment: i think we should back to topic, because do comment on `setElevation` make so many error, the new error : `Error:Execution failed for task ':UIAppTemplate:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ArrayRes.class`

Comment: I purchased Android Material from [here](http://goo.gl/RiS3Wy) and [it's doc](http://csform.com/documentation-for-ui-template-app-for-android/), but the vendor guy still not response...

Comment: @user2226388, Please accept this answer if it solved the problem you posted. Post your other problem as a new question as well instead of asking via comments.